# Setting Object of Javascript Class and then changing it somehow changes the object of all Instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

Im writing a project with Node.JS and something weird occured. Somehow if i call test1.changeObjName() it changes the value of all Instances of that class:

```
var myObj = {"name":"test"};
var myClass = function(){
    this.obj = myObj;
    this.changeObjName = function(){
        this.obj.name ="newValue";   
    };
};  
var test1 = new myClass();
var test2 = new myClass();

test1.changeObjName();

console.log(test1.obj.name); //returns "newValue"
console.log(test2.obj.name); //returns "newValue"
```

Why does `test1.changeObjName();` change the Value of `test2.obj.name` too? Now if i change the definition of this.obj to this:

```
var myClass = function(){
    this.obj = {"name":"test"};
    this.changeObjName = function(){
        this.obj.name ="newValue";   
    };
};  
var test1 = new myClass();
var test2 = new myClass();

test1.changeObjName();

console.log(test1.obj.name); //returns "newValue"
console.log(test2.obj.name); //returns "test"
```

It works as i expected. Whats the difference here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both have the same `this.obj` when you did:

```
this.obj = myObj
```

Notice that this just took the reference of the object sitting outside, every assignment through the constructor (i.e. when you initialize the class) will track the object outside. So every object will have the same `this.obj`, which is `myObj`. More over, any changes you do before instantiating the next object would also appear to have been applied to the new object.

In your second example though, you are creating a new object for every instance. In other words, each `this.obj` is different for every constructed object.